# Xcode/Swift problem with navigation bar resembling item

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

Hi I have this thing that comes up after I do a segue. Can someone tell me what it is and how to remove it. Thank you!
[The image (its the thing that allows you to see the previous view controller ,and you can swipe to go to it. )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MKll.png)

Comment: You've selected `Present Modally` segue.

Comment: Your question should never have been upvoted. Stackoverflow is for specific questions about coding. Please read about how to ask a question here. Your question is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the new presentation mode for `Presentation Modally` kind, comes with iOS 13. If you want to present the navigation, you have to create the `segue` selecting the `Show` option:
[image]